# AJAX update database

Tags: php, jquery

Sorry for not stated my problem. Actually I want to update my data in database.
But the problem now is even i tried to choose approve or reject the ajax still won't update.
I am new in ajax and try search around net but my code still got problem

here is my php page

```
<?php
          $querysel = "SELECT * FROM tblinternapplication WHERE course_code = '{$course_codeapp}' ORDER BY student_id, 1 DESC " ;
      $resultsel = mysql_query($querysel, $connection);

      echo "<h2><div class=\"h_title\">Status still in pending</div></h2>";  
      echo "<table>";
      echo "<thead>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<th scope=\"col\">Matric ID</th>";
      echo "<th scope=\"col\">Company name</th>";
      echo "<th scope=\"col\" width = \"200\">Job Scope</th>";
      echo "<th scope=\"col\">Status</th>";
      echo "<th scope=\"col\">Action</th>";
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "</thead>";

          while($rowsel = mysql_fetch_array($resultsel)){
                    if($rowsel['status_approval'] == NULL){
            $id = $rowsel['id'];
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<tr>"."<td class=\"align-center\">".$rowsel['student_id']."</td>";
                    echo "<td class=\"align-center\">".$rowsel['company_name']."</td>";
                    echo "<td class=\"align-center\" width = \"200\">".$rowsel['job_scope']."</td>";
        echo "<td class=\"align-center\">";
                    if($rowsel['status_approval'] != NULL){
                        if( $rowsel['status_approval'] == 0)
            {
               echo "Reject";
            }
            else
            {
               echo "Approve";
            }
                        }
                    else
                    {   echo "Pending";
                        }
                    echo "</td>";
        echo "<td class=\"align-center\"><select name=\"approve\" 
         onchange=\"getstatus(this.value)\">";
            echo "<option value=\"\">Select status:</option>";
            echo "<option value=\"1\">Approve</option>";
            echo "<option value=\"0\">Reject</option>";
        echo "</select>";
        echo "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";

                    }
      }
      echo "</table>";
```

here is my jscript page

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function getstatus(id, approve)
{
if (approve=="")
{
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","updatestatus.php?id=" + id + "&status=" + approve,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

then here is my updatestatus.php

```
<?php require_once("../includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("sessioncourse.php"); ?>
<?php $course_codeapp = $_SESSION['course_code'] ; ?>
<?php confirm_logged_in(); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/connection.php") ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php") ?>

<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
$status =$_GET['status'];

$sql="UPDATE tblinternapplication set status_approval  = $status WHERE id = $id ";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

I work for few days but problem still cannot solve. Hope someone can help me. I will appreciate your help!

Comment: I recommend you to use jquery-ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ it's a lot easier

Comment: Agreed, if you're using jquery already there's no good reason not to use $.ajax()

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) holes in your code. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<td class=\"align-center\"><select name=\"approve\" 
         onchange=\"getstatus(this.value)\">";
```

In that line above, you are passing only one value. At the same time your JS function waits for 2 parameters. Currently, you have `id` always equal to 0 or 1 and status is always undefined. 
Suppose you just need to change that line like:

```
echo "<td class=\"align-center\"><select name=\"approve\" 
         onchange=\"getstatus("+ $id +", this.value)\">";
```

**One note:**

```
$sql="UPDATE tblinternapplication set status_approval  = $status WHERE id = $id ";
```

Except that you should not use mysql_* functions anymore, code above is opened to sql injections. To avoid sql injections with mysql_ extension you should do something like this:

```
 $sql="UPDATE tblinternapplication set status_approval  = ".mysql_real_escape_string($status) ." WHERE id = " .mysql_real_escape_string($id);
```

See docs for `mysql_real_escape_string` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). Also, read a warning message on that page - it tells you what you should use in replacement for mysql extension

Comment: thank you so much! Thanks for help me state out the problem i change the getstatus to getstatus($id,this.value). it's work perfectly. and i try using escape and give me the output that i want.thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For preapre result for JS in php use json_encode() function. Make your update script somthing like this:

```
<?php require_once("../includes/session.php"); 
require_once("sessioncourse.php"); 
$course_codeapp = $_SESSION['course_code'] ; 
confirm_logged_in(); 
require_once("../includes/connection.php"); 
require_once("../includes/functions.php"); 

$id = $_GET['id'];
$status =$_GET['status'];

$sql="UPDATE tblinternapplication set status_approval  = $status WHERE id = $id ";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$json = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $json[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

#### IMPORTANT

Dont close php tag or you may add extra space chars

### AJAX

In your case using jQuery ajax was good practic. Mkae you code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getstatus(id, approve)
    {
        $.ajax({
            'url': 'updatestatus.php',
            'data': {"id": id, "status": approve},
            'success': function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                //TODO: use server response
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much! finally I can update and thanks for teaching jquery ajax which make me more easy to understand=D but can I ask something? why must put json_encode?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the developer tools like F12 in IE or chrome or the fiddler to check the request you are sending to the PHP code . In case you are getting any error you can easily see in the response